# Create virtual disk from some of the partitions on physical device

Tags: virtualbox, partitioning, clone

I am in the process of migrating windows installation to a VM.  On the physical device with windows, there are two partitions: `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`.  There's also a large amount of free space following the second partition.

I can create a virtual disk off the full `/dev/sda` easily with this command:

```
cat /dev/sdg | VBoxManage convertfromraw stdin OutPutFile.vdi NUMBEROFBYTES
```

However this will create a huge file, which will include all the free space.  I want the file to only include the two partitions.  How can I do this?  Alternatively, is there an option to resize **down** the virtual disk after it's created?

Comment: Why not shrink the partition first?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 The partition is already the correct size.  I don't want to include the non-partitioned space in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's all quite easy.  Here's what my partition table looked like:

```
   Device Boot       Start           End       Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *         2048        526335       262144    7  NTFS
/dev/sdb2           526336   92342323199  46170898432    7  NTFS
Unpartitioned  92342323200  234076243969  70866960384
```

I could create a virtual disk from this entire physical disk with the command:

```
cat /dev/sdg | VBoxManage convertfromraw stdin OutPutFile.vdi 117038121985
```

This would create a virtual disk with the two NTFS partitions and another 66 GB of empty space.  As I didn't want the empty space, all I had to do was to specify the `NUMBEROFBYTES` to be the two partitions I needed (plus I added a little extra to be on the safer side). This command:

```
cat /dev/sdg | VBoxManage convertfromraw stdin OutPutFile.vdi 46171161600
```

would create the virtual disk with just the two partitions.